# A limit problem $0\log \cfrac{0}{0}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, information-theory

How can we show that $$0\log \cfrac{0}{0}=0 ?$$

PS. Not homework. This is taken as a convention in the book Elements of Information Theory by Cover. And the books claims it's by continuity (Page 31). It is used in other places in the book too.

[image]

and Page 19

[image]

The copy rights of these extracts belongs to the book publisher. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what the original prblem was before zero was "substituted" into the problem?

Comment: Such an expression is undefined. You can't apply any rule, because it doesn't denote a number. You have some functions, probably; of course the limit depends on what these functions are.

Comment: It is not a problem, it was assumed in the book Elements of information theory - Cover Edition 2 page 31.

Comment: $\dfrac1{\ln\ln n}\cdot \ln\dfrac{1/n}{1/n^2} \not\to 0$.

Comment: Again: some context is needed, because the expression is meaningless as is.

Comment: Well, without a limit notation to have at least, this expression means nothing...

Comment: Book does not use limit notation.

Comment: @MLT, if  what you wrote in your question is written *just like that* in that book then it is huge abuse of notation. Most probably there's written a different expression...

Comment: @DonAntonio I pasted the extract from the book. Thanks

Comment: Well, I'd definitely never, ever use a book that explain things like that, *even* to non-mathematicians. That is, and looks, gross and even worse: it blasphemously mentions continuity...oh, how the Earth doesn't open and swallows that book's author!

Comment: This is the standard book in information theory in almost every university.

Comment: If what you say is true @MLT, my heart bleeds for the information theory's students in almost every university, and I duly present my deepest mathematical condolences to them all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the book. In short, there is an inequality of the form "something $\ge a \log \dfrac bc$", where the right hand side is interpreted to be $0$ in case $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Even at MIT http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-441-information-theory-spring-2010/readings/ and  Stanford http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/reading.html

Comment: @UmbertoP., that still makes no sense mathematically, which what we're discussing here: you can **not** , mathematically, divide by zero and also not "evaluate" $\;\log(0)\;$ .

Comment: @MLT , as already said: my heart continues to bleed for those students, even if they belong to Ivy League universities.

Comment: There's a reason why this is called a *convention* in that book

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen , perhaps so...but that, as far as I know, is "not" a mathematicians convention. One of the answers below mentions "defining"...that's, imo, better.

Comment: As the authors said it, the continuity argument here works only for $0\log\frac{0}{q}$ and not $0\log\frac{0}{0}$!the later is just convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_n=y_n=1/n$ and $z_n=\mathrm e^{-n^2}$, then
$$
x_n\log(y_n/z_n)\to+\infty\quad\text{and}\quad x_n\log(z_n/y_n)\to-\infty,
$$
Since  $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\to(0,0,0)$ and $(x_n,z_n,y_n)\to(0,0,0)$, this "implies" that
$$
0\log(0/0)=+\infty\quad\text{and}\quad 0\log(0/0)=-\infty.
$$
**Edit:** (addressing some concerns raised by the revised version of the question and some exchanges in the comments)
For every positive $x$ and $y$, define $h(x,y)=x\log(x/y)$. Then $h$ has limits on the axes $[x=0,y\gt0]$ and $[x\gt0,y=0]$ since, for every $x\gt0$, $\lim\limits_{y\to0}h(x,y)=+\infty$, and, for every $y\gt0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}h(x,y)=0$. But $h$ has no limit at $(0,0)$.

To see this, note that $(x,\mathrm e^{-1/x^2})\to(0,0)$ and $h(x,\mathrm e^{-1/x^2})\to+\infty$ when $x\to0$ and that $(x,x)\to(0,0)$ and $h(x,x)\to0$ when $x\to0$. Likewise, for every positive $c$, $(x,\mathrm e^{-c/x})\to(0,0)$ and $h(x,\mathrm e^{-c/x})\to c$ when $x\to0$.

To sum up, $x\log(x/y)$ could be assigned *any value* in $[0,+\infty]$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Hence, somewhat more wisely, $x\log(x/y)$ should be assigned *no value* at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please comment in the case when  $x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$ are probability distributions in real numbers? Will the convention hold then?

Comment: The numbers in the example are all real numbers in $(0,1]$ hence they are already probabilities. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I mean the functions $x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$ should integrate up to 1 for example $\intop x_n=1$ and for $y_n$ and $z_n$ too. Like probability distributions. Thanks.

Comment: Your question mentions $0\log(0/0)$. Are you in fact interested in *sums* of these? If so, complete $x_n$, $y_n$ and $z_n$ by $x'_n=1-x_n$, $y'_n=1-y_n$ and $z'_n=1-z_n$, getting probabilities on a two-point probability space.

Comment: Yes, but the book use it in general for probability mass functions and density functions. So I was wondering if it at least hold for such cases. Also could you explain what continuity has to do with this? Thank you.

Comment: Continuity? Dunno, no continuity in my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand why you defined three functions. Could you please explain why you didn't use $n\log\cfrac{n}{n}$ and let $n$ go to zero? isn't that how limits are proved?

Comment: Because you never said that the question was to find the limit of $x\log(x/x)$ when $x\to0$ and because the question is certainly not that since $x\log(x/x)=0$ for every $x\gt0$ and since some explanations in the document you inserted in your question after I posted my answer consider quantities like $p\log(p/q)$ with $p\ne q$ (note that my first example deals with $x\log(x/z)$ when $x\to0$ and $z\to0$, that is, exactly the regime you ought to be interested in).

Comment: Thank you. I think I am close to understanding you answer. Yes that is my point because you posted your answer before I included that other excerpt. So could you please explain why you claim the question can not be that "since $x\log\cfrac{x}{x}=0$ for every x>0". While I understand what you say here as a statement, I don't understand how that could nullify the question.

Comment: (1) Too obvious. (2) Not the case in formulas for entropies.

Comment: Thank you. So in conclusion do you disagree with the convention used in the book that $0\log\cfrac{0}{0}=0$ by continuity? Because as I understand it is not continuous at (0,0) right?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: I completely disagree with this conclusion.  The definition $0\log 0/0 = 0$ is almost always leads to the  correct solution in information theory.

Comment: @MikeMcCoy OK, you disagree. Did you read ANY argument given before the conclusion (so that we know what we are talking about)?

Comment: @Did I certainly understand that different limiting behavior gives different results.  The point is that, in information theory, without limits involved, the rule gives the "correct thing to do."  Other potential limiting values are simply wrong in the context of probability zero events.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, in information theory context, Kullback-Leibler divergence is defined for two probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ as follows:
$$
D(P||Q)=\sum_{x\in S} P(x)\log \left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right).
$$ 
where $S$ is sample space of $x$. In this context, talking about the value of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ is both zero for a given $x$, then *conventionally* they define $0\log\frac{0}{0}=0$.

For the cases where $Q(x)\neq 0$ but $P(x)=0$, this is somehow intuitive as $x\log x\rightarrow 0$  when $x\to 0$. However in case  $Q(x)= 0$, this becomes less intuitive.

However saying $0\log\frac{0}{0}=0$ is mathematically speaking and out of its context, meaningless. In any case, these definitions are just conventions for avoiding unpleasant situations and are used often to circumvent the occasional difficulties. But it does not mean in any sens that $0\log\frac{0}{0}=0$ in general. It is just **adding points**, to domain of a function.

Comment: Oh! If they *do define* that as this and that then I've no problem at all...yet there still **is** a mathematical, even if pretty elementary, explanation.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I meant $x\to 0$ indeed, corrected.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I do not think that information theorists are mathematically so illiterate that put such strange expressions in their official texts. It is just a definition there.

Comment: Well, it looked that way at first, @Arash...even the definition,  as accepted as it can be, is pretty strange since by limits one can easily show stuff. And let's not forget that book mentions continuity, so I'm not sure why it won't talk of "limits"...

Comment: @DonAntonio, I read that book years ago. There are some slips somewhere but I am certain that they do not talk about limits. That would be really insane. Regarding definitions, they can re-define a function at certain points and get a new function. They should be careful about the consequences later.

Comment: @Arash Thank you very much. Could you also please explain why book claims "by continuity"?

Comment: The continuity argument concerns only $0\log 0$ and not what you wrote. As I explained here $x\log x$ goes to zero as $x\to 0$. For the other one, continuity argument does not work and Cover-Thomas do  not claim it either.

Comment: It says "these follow" so for my English knowledge (not a native English speaker) that means all of those 3 claims follow from continuity. I didn't write it, it's a picture from the book. Thanks

Comment: @MLT, Well, I see what you mean. I only looked at the definition of KL divergence. Concerning the first part, unfortunately this is wrong. There is no continuity argument in the context of log-sum inequality which justifies such equality.

Comment: @MLT, The authors are more careful in their next statement but the first part is dangerously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue at hand is the log-sum inequality: if $a_k$ and $b_k$ are sequences of nonnegative numbers, then $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \log \left( \frac{a_k}{b_k} \right) \ge \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right) \log \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k }{ \sum_{k=1}^n b_k}$$

If $a_j$ and $b_j$ are nonzero for at least one index $j$, the right-hand-side makes sense, and the inequality still holds if **for the purposes of this proposition only** you take $0 \log \frac 0 0 = 0$ when necessary on the left hand side.

Comment: This is the context of the comment in the book.

Comment: Actually the book use the convention in many places not just in log sum inequality. See the definition of relative entropy (Page 19) please.

Comment: That's why he uses the word "again". The convention is used whenever appropriate and is pointed out each time.

Comment: Still book never explains how it comes from continuity as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are a bit too complicated for my taste.  Most people are willing to accept the definition $0\log(0) = 0$, which authors often justify because

$$ x \log(x) \to 0 \text{ as } x \to 0.$$

(Use L'Hopital's rule.)  Then we can  interpret the ratio as a difference

$$ 0 \log\frac{0}{0} = 0 \log 0 - 0 \log 0 = 0.$$

(Forgive me, oh mathgods, for this blasphemy.)

The real answer is, of course, we take that as definition because it makes sense for information theory. When computing the entropy over a countable space, points with zero probability should be ommitted in your computation; this jives with "$0\log 0 =0$.  When computing the relative entropy of events, you should only ignore points of zero probability under *both* events, and hence the rule $0\log(0/0)=0$.

Comment: This implicitely assumes that one is considering the limit of $x\log(x/x)$. One is not.

Comment: @Did Of course not (but that's the least of the mathematical rules that I broke). Indeed, your answer shows that any limiting argument justifying this rule is specious. The real answer is "because that rule is usually the right thing to do". I still think that the heuristic above is generally more palatable than trying to take different limiting behavior into account, but it is, strictly speaking, wrong.

Comment: If the argument implicitely assumes one is considering $x\log(x/x)$ and one is not assuming that, one wonders what the argument shows. Even if a rule is true, a wrong argument designed to show that this rule holds is just that: a wrong argument. Yes "we can interpret the ratio as a difference", but not the difference you lead us to believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author probably had in mind the following statement:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}x\log \left( \frac{x}{x}\right)=0,$$
which is obvious. The more general statement
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+,y\rightarrow 0^+}x\log \left( \frac{x}{y}\right)=0,$$
doesn't hold, and that seems to be the most relevant statement in that context. To see this, take $y(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$. As $x\rightarrow 0^+$, we have $y(x)\rightarrow 0^+$, but
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\log \left( \frac{x}{y(x)}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\left[\log x+x\frac{1}{x}\right]\rightarrow 1.$$
My take on it is: just take it as a convention. It is a definition, so it doesn't need justification; it's a matter of convenience.